# Is there possibility to load all rows of table to array in JTable of Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla2.5

I use Joomla 2.5 framework.
I have simple table such as:

```
int id
string itemid
```

Now I just want to load all 'itemid's to array using JTable. Is here possibility?

Comment: Some one... May be I need to use other method?

Comment: I know this is an old question but if I can find it so can someone else. I'm new to Joomla but there are some rules to follow, such as using singular and plural names for models and controllers.

What you are trying to do is load a list which would be covered by a plural name in Joomla. For this create a new Model extending JModelList. In that Model you would provide at least 1 function, getListQuery.

In that function you would create a query which would take care of how to load a list of the items and return the query.

JTables are used when you are working with single items, not lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I decided to use is inherit model class from JModelList:

```
class modelModelcomponent extends JModelList
{
        protected function getListQuery()
        {
            // Create a new query object.           
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Select some fields
            $query->select('itemid');

            // From the hello table
            $query->from('#__table');

            return $query;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything about the JTable Class only deals with one row, as soon as multiple rows are involved, you have two options:

1) Use the solution you gave.

2) Override the load() function in your Table class. This can be done as under:

Put the following load() function in your Table class:

```
 function load($key = null)
    {

            $db = $this->getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select($key);
            $query->from($this->getTableName());
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $row = $db->loadRowList();

             if ($db->getErrorNum()) 
             {
                $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                return false;
             }

            // Check that we have a result.

            if (empty($row)) 
            {
                    return false;
            }

            //Return the array
            return $row;


    }
```

Now call the load() function with a single argument 'itemid', and get the array you want.

This worked for me, hope it helps you too.